# Обработка созданный кнопок

Tags: javascript

есть 2 проблемы:
1)в первый раз кнопка срабатывает на 1 нажатия,во все последующие разы необходимо совершать двойной клик.

```
<button  data-dialog-close >record</button>


function DialogFx( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this.ctrlClose = this.el.querySelector( '[data-dialog-close]' );
        this.isOpen = false;
        this._initEvents();
    }

    DialogFx.prototype.options = {
        // callbacks
        onOpenDialog : function() { return false; },
        onCloseDialog : function() { return false; }
    }

    DialogFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;

        // close action
        тут косяк--> this.ctrlClose.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggle.bind(this) );


        this.el.querySelector( '.dialog__overlay' ).addEventListener( 'click', this.toggle.bind(this) );
    }




    DialogFx.prototype.toggle = function() {
        var self = this;
        if( this.isOpen ) {
            classie.remove( this.el, 'dialog--open' );
            classie.add( self.el, 'dialog--close' );

            onEndAnimation( this.el.querySelector( '.dialog__content' ), function() {
                classie.remove( self.el, 'dialog--close' );
            } );

            // callback on close
            this.options.onCloseDialog( this );
        }
        else {
            classie.add( this.el, 'dialog--open' );

            // callback on open
            this.options.onOpenDialog( this );
        }
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    };

    // add to global namespace
    window.DialogFx = DialogFx;
```

2)если ,к примеру,кнопки создаются на странице программно,то этот код не работает,как правильно их обрабатывать?
Тут пример http://jsfiddle.net/ed0coLdw/6/, но тут все работает проблема именно в том,что данные создаются (из базы ajax выводятся) и выводятся в нужном формате

Comment: добавьте описание _extend_, пример html и пример как вызываете вашу функцию

Comment: данную строку `this.options = extend( {}, this.options );` можно заменить на `this.options = {}` - ведь в момент вызова конструктора у вас это поле всегда undefined

Comment: @Grundy, не помогло это

Comment: А это и не решение было :-) это просто небольшой недочет. Вы приведете _описание extend, пример html и пример как вызываете вашу функцию_?

Comment: а почему на jsfiddle код отличается от того что приведен в вопросе?

Comment: тут просто не полный

Comment: да и там похоже порядок чуть поменян. Можете все-таки сделать пример который именно воспроизводит как у вас? возможно влияют сторонние библиотеки или код?

Comment: Вся проблема в данных,который берутся из базы,форматируются под нужный вид и я  их обрабатываю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35495/discussion-between-grundy-and-zkolya).

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему я бы не делал такого мудреного кода все на много проще можно сделать. если вам действительно нужен текст и одна кнопка.

```
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >1</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >2</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >3</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >4</div><br>
<div  data-dialog="somedialog" class="trigger" >5</div><br>
<div id="somedialog" class="dialog">
    <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
    <div class="dialog__content">
        <p>Диалоговое окно</p>
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="dialog-close-btn action" data-dialog-close>Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


(function(){
    var $dialogTemplate;

    $(function(){
        $dialogTemplate = $('.dialog').detach();
    });

    var showDialog = function() {
        var $dialog = $dialogTemplate.clone();
        $(document.body).append($dialog);
    };

    var removeDialog = function() {
        $('.dialog').remove();
    };

    $(document).on('click', '.trigger', showDialog);
    $(document).on('click', '.dialog-close-btn', removeDialog);
})();
```

Это Вам реально упростит задачу.